# Export an imported module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two javascript modules that looks like this:

```
// inner/mod.js
export function myFunc() {
   // ...
}

// mod.js
import * as inner from "./inner/mod";
```

I would like to export `myFunc` from `mod.js`. How can I do this?

EDIT: I should clarify that the function is being exported as expected from `inner/mod.js` but I also want to export the funtion from the outer `mod.js`.

To those asking for clarification, I would like to achieve this:

```
// SomeOtherFile.js
import * as mod from "mod"; // NOT inner/mod

mod.myFunc();
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No I'm not getting an error. But I'm also not exporting anything from `mod`. Notice there are no export statements.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are expecting to use this elsewhere? I'm not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: I've updated the question to provide an example.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
export * from './inner/mod';
```

That will reexports all exports of `./inner/mod`. The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-source-text-module-records) actually has very nice tables listing all the possible [`import`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#table-40) and [`export`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#table-42) variants.

Comment: The only way that seems to work is `import mod from "./inner/mod"; export {mod}`. Using `export * from './inner/mod';` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually, it does work. It doesn't work, however, if `inner/mod` exports a default function.

Comment: Yep, that will only cover named exports. You can explicitly export the default export with `export {default} from './inner/mod';`.

Comment: with firebase cloud functions, in typescript :

File A (sub file)
`export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);`

File B (index)
`export * from './api';`

Answer (score 35):

```
// inner/mod.js
export function myFunc() {
   // ...
}

// mod.js
import { myFunc } from "./inner/mod";
export { myFunc };
```

Try to be explicit in what you import, the less the better, because of that I've changed your import in mod.js. If you **do** import *, you define a variable which will be the object of all names exports from that module you imported.

re-exporting is the same as making something of your own and exporting.

Comment: Is it possible to export the entire object? I want to have an `index` module that exports all of the sub-modules.

Comment: Ow yes it is, you can export anything static, objects, arrays, strings, numbers etc. What happens is that everything exported goed into a key-value object. The key being the name of the export, the value the .. well the thing you're exporting of course.. You can't export expressions.

Comment: I'm using babel to convert es6 to es5. Using your example I get an unexpected token on `export myFunc`.

Comment: Updated the code, does this work? I've only been using this syntax myself for a few days, http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html is an amazing resource.

Comment: `export {myFunc as myFunc};` can be written as `export {myFunc};`.